# I duplicated my project and now I get a Ruby/Sass error

Tags: ruby, angular-fullstack

My Angular Fullstack project works fine when I run grunt serve. I duplicated the project on my machine to start a new project and now I'm getting the following error in the terminal:

[image]

I made no changes in the duplicated project. I'm afraid to tamper with the current path of my gems in fear I'll stop the projects that are working well from working.

Comment: How are you managing your gems? You may need to reinstall them in the new directory.

Comment: @pdoherty926 Since I did not get any timely help I've put a band-aid on it with a work around for now. Maybe I will follow up on this later. Thank you.